# call add-migration inside controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

i want the developer when they add something in ef code first they go to page say run_migration_page hit the button and call the add-migration and update-database functionality. I know it is existing when there is an error but i want to copy that functionality

Comment: Add-Migration or Update-Database? Adding a C# file to the app from the app seems unusual... To apply migrations, just call `dbContext.Database.Migrate()`

Comment: @bricelam both Add-Migration and Update-Database how it is being applied in controller?